# Increment an Index Counter in Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a View model that has an `IEnumerable` object that I loop through to display a data table. The model also has an array of values that I would like to display within the same table.

The enumerable data is displayed with a `foreach` loop. I've tried adding an index counter to loop through the array on the same table, but the counter never increments. How can I combine both elements in the same table?

```
        //my foreach loop goes through my Item List
        @foreach (var item in @Model.ItemList)
        {
            //i need an indexer to go through MyArray
            var i = 0;
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.StartDate)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.EndDate)</td><td>@Model.MyArray[i]</td><td>@item.Value</td>
            </tr>
            //here the index 'i' never seems to increment
            i++;
        }
```

The result is that only `MyArray[0]` value is displayed for all rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every time the code gets inside the loop your "i" gets set to zero. You have to initialize your counter outside of the loop like this:

```
@{
    // Here the initialization happens outside of the loop
    var i = 0;
} 

@foreach (var item in @Model.ItemList)
{      
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.StartDate)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.EndDate)</td><td>@Model.MyArray[i]</td><td>@item.Value</td>
    </tr>
    //here your index should increment correctly
    i++;
}
```

Otherwise, you can find your index just by this:

```
int index = @Model.ItemList.IndexOf(item);
<tr>
    ...
    <td>
      @index
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

inside your loop.

Comment: How do I initialize the indexer in this case. When I use the code you suggest, I get an error. I've also tried `@var i = 0` and I also get an error

Comment: Thank you, using the `Model.ItemList.IndexOf(item)` did the trick

Comment: @coolhand I also added the necessary Razor syntax for the initialization to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop instead of foreach.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ItemList.Count(); i++)
{
    var item = Model.ItemList[i];
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.StartDate)</td><td>@Html.DisplayFor(shortDate => item.EndDate)</td><td>@Model.MyArray[i]</td><td>@item.Value</td>
    </tr>
}
```